# Remove unwanted characters from phone number string

Tags: python, regex

I am aiming for regex code to grab phone number and remove unneeded characters.

```
import re
strs = 'dsds +48 124 cat cat cat245 81243!!'
match = re.search(r'.[ 0-9\+\-\.\_]+', strs)

if match:                      
    print 'found', match.group() ## 'found word:cat'
else:
    print 'did not find'
```

It returns only:

```
+48 124
```

How I can return the entire number?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to use [`sub()`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub), not `search()`:

```
>>> strs = 'dsds +48 124 cat cat cat245 81243!!'
>>> re.sub(r"[^0-9+._ -]+", "", strs)
' +48 124   245 81243'
```

`[^0-9+._ -]` is a [negated character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). The `^` is significant here - this expression means: "Match a characters that is neither a digit, nor a plus, a dot, an underscore, a space or a dash".

The `+` tells the regex engine to match one or more instances of the preceding token.

Comment: But what if some data has alpha number entries and we need both alpha numeric data but not the extra brackets or commas.

Answer (score 5):

The problem with `re.sub()` is that you get extra spaces in your final phone number string.  The non-regular expression way, which returns the correct phone number (without any spaces):

```
>>> strs = 'dsds +48 124 cat cat cat245 81243!!'
>>> ''.join(x for x in strs if x.isdigit() or x == '+')
'+4812424581243'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use to replace all non-digits with a single
hyphen, and it seems to work for me:

```
# convert sequences of non-digits to a single hyphen
fixed_phone = re.sub("[^\d]+","-",raw_phone)
```